# Reference for measures of commutativity needed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

I'm looking for an appropriate measure to quantify the extent to which two matrices commute. In other words, if $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices, and $[A,B]=C$.

I'd like a function $\mu : \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $\mu(C)=0$ if the two operators commute and maybe obeys some other properties that I haven't quite figured out yet. Otherwise, a function $\nu(A,B): \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ could be good. Clearly the absolute value of the trace of the commutator, determinant, norms, etc, are candidates, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a review of different measures and their relative strengths/weaknesses.

I'm ultimately looking to construct a measure that behaves something like the Kullbeck-Leibler divergence ([quantum relative entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_relative_entropy)), but where we wind up with a value $\nu(A,B)=0$ in the event that the two operators commute and $\nu(A,B) > 0$ if they do not.

A link to some lecture notes, a paper/book reference would be appreciated, or just being pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: At a first glance I would think that taking $\|C\|$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$ is the more natural way to go here.  I'm not familiar with the kind of thing you're trying to do, though.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, I'm just afraid that my perspective is a bit naive and maybe someone has a more comprehensive knowledge of this. (I can't seem to navigate google to an answer on this.)

Comment: Since this does look like a research level question, it might be better to post it to [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/).  I'm not sure if questions can be migrated there or if you would need to make a new post.

Comment: Yes, I'll do so in an hour or so after giving it some time here. Thanks!

Comment: Added a few tags for more visibility.  Good luck

Comment: Now posted to MO, without notifying either site: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207126/reference-for-measures-of-commutativity-needed

Comment: Is there a standard way to do this? I should have included a link, I guess?